# How To Add Event Handlers to Controls in a clss inheriting ITemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, itemplate

I've made a Template for adding controls to a DetailsView I have from code behind.

```
private class edgFooterTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private Button btn_Edit;

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        btn_Edit = new Button();
        btn_Edit.CausesValidation = false;
        btn_Edit.CommandName = "Edit";
        btn_Edit.ID = "btn_Edit";
        btn_Edit.Text = "Edit";
        container.Controls.Add(btn_Edit);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want to add an event handler on the control but I can't access btn_Edit in the DetailsView I made from code-behind as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could init your edit button e.g. in the template constructor and add an edit click event to the template:

```
private class edgFooterTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private Button btn_Edit;

    public edgFooterTemplate()
    {
        btn_Edit = new Button();
        btn_Edit.CausesValidation = false;
        btn_Edit.CommandName = "Edit";
        btn_Edit.ID = "btn_Edit";
        btn_Edit.Text = "Edit";
    }

    public event EventHandler EditClick
    {
        add { this.btn_Edit.Click += value; }
        remove { this.btn_Edit.Click -= value; }
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        if (container != null)
        {
            container.Controls.Add(btn_Edit);
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it from the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var footerTemplate = new edgFooterTemplate();
    footerTemplate.EditClick += new EventHandler(footerTemplate_EditClick);
    viewItems.FooterTemplate = footerTemplate;
}
```

and, finally, the event handler:

```
protected void footerTemplate_EditClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some logic here
}
```